# How to get a message id based on the ticket id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a ticket system and trying to add an edit feature.
and I was wondering how do I get the selected message-id that I have chosen to select.
The far as I have got is hard coding the id into the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true)
{
    require '../../config.php';
    $ticketMsg = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ticket_msgs WHERE ticket_id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id'])."'");
    $edit = $conn->query("UPDATE `ticket_msgs` SET `ticket_msg` = 'Testing' WHERE `ticket_msgs`.`id` = ");

    if($edit)
    {
        header("location: ./index.php");
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `UPDATE ticket_msgs SET ticket_msg = 'Testing' WHERE ticket_id=:id` why not directly?

Comment: Will that work with our database config? We have a message id the message and the ticket id

Comment: After doing this. All ticket messages have been set to testing

Comment: That syntax was assuming you were going to use a prepared statement and parameter (which you must, in order to avoid potential SQL injection). Did you adjust your code accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

With mysql PDO:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE ticket_msgs SET ticket_msg=:msg WHERE id=:id';

// prepare statement
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

// bind params
$statement->bindParam(':msg', $ticketMsg);
$statement->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

// execute the UPDATE statement
if ($statement->execute()) {
    // updated, go to your index page
    header("location: ./index.php");
}
```

Comment: Good, expect OP is using the older mysqli extension.

Comment: @Dharman mysqli isn't "older", as far as I know, it's just a different style

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but i am getting an error adding this to my code https://prnt.sc/1qdus65

Comment: @Knifeworm sounds like your connection handle isn't initialized (therefore it is of type `boolean` with value=`false`). Try to connect like this: `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);` before using `$conn`.

Comment: Or use more DB-agnostic approach with PDO style connection in case your (potential) future intention is to change DBMS.